# Separate application Logging for managed servers in Weblogic12c cluster

Tags: logging, weblogic, cluster-computing

I am using Weblogic 12c as application server. The Weblogic server domain contains 2 managed servers which are in cluster. The EAR is to be deployed in a cluster (managed servers having same physical location).

**Now I want to have separate application logging to be done for each managed servers, as each managed server will be running its own copy of EAR. How I can achieve this thing.**

The log4j property file is present inside my ear.

I tried giving relative path in the properties file as mentioned below, but it didn't work:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=./log/appLog.log
```

The log file got created inside `domains/<my domain>/log/appLog.log`, which is not my requirement.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your log4j config file, use the variable ${weblogic.Name} in the path of log files.

Comment: can you please edit the question or so....by mistake I voted down ...wnat to give upvote and does not let me now to upvote until the question is edited. cheers Cris

Comment: Opps i was able to edit myself by adding a point and upvote after

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an admin server and two managed server.

Admin Server:

```
[WL_HOME]/user_projects/domains/[domain_name]/servers/AdminServer/logs
```

The app logs you should found on each server.
Be sure you target the managed servers (cluster) when you deploy the app.

Server 1 node:

```
[WL_HOME]/user_projects/domains/[domain_name]/servers/[server_1_name]/logs
```

Server 2 node:

```
[WL_HOME]/user_projects/domains/[domain_name]/servers/[server_2_name]/logs
```

A sample of an appender I use

```
<appender name="APPNAME-FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="logs/APPNAME-${weblogic.Name}.log"/>
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB"/>
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
<param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
</layout>
</appender>
```

The "logs/APPNAME-${weblogic.Name}.log might do the trick for you...

not ./logs

Comment: This only applies to WebLogic Server logs, not application logs.